# How to iterate over a dataframe with publish date column to make a daily mapping table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, dataframe

I'm using Python 3.7 for this task. 
I have a dataframe that stores blog ids, blog names and publish dates. I need to convert that to a new dataframe that will map every single day and URL to what the ID was. I'd need to this to run through the previous day's date (20191103 as of writing this). Assumptions include that an article can't be republished twice in one day and that no blog needs to have any dates prior to its publish date.

Example:

```
data = [[1234, 'Blog1', 20191030], [1235,'Blog1', 20191101], [1237,'Blog1', 20191102], [1236,'Blog2', 20191101]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Blog Name', 'Publish Date'])
df.head()
```

Starting Dataframe:

```
     ID  Blog Name  Publish Date
0   1234    Blog1   20191030
1   1235    Blog1   20191101
2   1237    Blog1   20191102
3   1236    Blog2   20191101
```

Goal: Final Dataframe:

```
   Blog Name  Date    ID
0   Blog1   20191030 1234
1   Blog1   20191031 1234
2   Blog1   20191101 1235
3   Blog1   20191102 1237
4   Blog1   20191103 1237
5   Blog1   20191101 1236
6   Blog2   20191102 1236
7   Blog2   20191103 1236
```

I'm mainly unsure of how to best iterate over the dataframe, do I create another column in the original dataframe with a "next publish date", then create a row in the new dataframe for every date between "publish date" and "next publish date"?

Solution: (Courtesy of Code Different)

```
# Your Publish Date column is string, Need to convert it to Timestamp
df['Publish Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Publish Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

def summarize(g):
    # A date range that covers from the first Publish Date to the current day
    d = pd.date_range(g['Publish Date'].min(), pd.Timestamp.now(), name='Publish Date').to_frame(index=False)

    # The merge. This also has the effect of filling any gap in the
    # Publish Date
    return pd.merge_asof(d, g, on='Publish Date')


df.sort_values(['Blog Name', 'Publish Date']) \
    .groupby('Blog Name').apply(summarize) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: do you need to repeat each record until the next day that have a record?

Comment: @phalanx yeah, I need to repeat each record until the previous day (relative to current day)

Answer (score 1):

A perfect job for `merge_asof`:

```
# Your Publish Date column is string, Need to convert it to Timestamp
df['Publish Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Publish Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

def summarize(g):
    # A date range that covers from the first Publish Date to the current day
    d = pd.date_range(g['Publish Date'].min(), pd.Timestamp.now(), name='Publish Date').to_frame(index=False)

    # The merge. This also has the effect of filling any gap in the
    # Publish Date
    return pd.merge_asof(d, g, on='Publish Date')


df.sort_values(['Blog Name', 'Publish Date']) \
    .groupby('Blog Name').apply(summarize) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result (assuming today = `2019-11-04`):

```
  Publish Date    ID Blog Name
0   2019-10-30  1234     Blog1
1   2019-10-31  1234     Blog1
2   2019-11-01  1235     Blog1
3   2019-11-02  1237     Blog1
4   2019-11-03  1237     Blog1
5   2019-11-04  1237     Blog1
6   2019-11-01  1236     Blog2
7   2019-11-02  1236     Blog2
8   2019-11-03  1236     Blog2
9   2019-11-04  1236     Blog2
```

Comment: That's perfect! Much better than any shenanigans I had planned :)